# Laravel Validator::setFiles() is undefined why?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am trying to validate uploaded images but get an error that `setFiles()` method is undefined.  But the method does exist and I have verified that in the Validator class and checked the Docs.

[setFiles API Documentation](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_setFiles)

```
// Process Image Uploads
if (Input::hasFile('images')) {
    // Validate Images
    $validate = new Validator;
    $validate->setFiles(Input::file('images'));
    $validate->setRules('max:20000|mimes:jpeg');

    if ($validate->passes()) 
        return 'Passes';
    else
        return 'Fails';
}
```

**Error**

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::setFiles()`

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be honest, things written in API docs is quite hard to understand. I used to read laravel docs even though the docs is not fully perfect enough.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

You should use instance validator by static method `make` instead of constructor. So it should be looks like this.

```
// Validate Images
$rules = ['images' => 'max:20000|mimes:jpeg'];
$validate = Validator::make(Input::all(),$rules);
// process the form
if ($validator->fails()) {
    var_dump($validator->errors());  // it will print the error logs for you.
} else {
    return 'success';
}
```